# How can I make a Pygame game executable online?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a website for a university project where you can play some minigames I've programmed with Pygame (Python). How can I make the games executable online (like flashgames)? I'm using php

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you to be more specific in what you need, and also to post whatever attempt you have for what you are trying to achieve. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can’t. There is (unfortunately) no way to run Python with pygame as a web application.

Comment: I'm also finding a way to realize it, but I only find a good way by web socket.But I think it's will make a delay problem. Skuplt maybe a good way to realize by js. I'm looking for another way.

Answer (score 0):

### **PYGAME ON WEB**(Pygbag)

Now you can run pygame in browser using the **pygbag**,for more details you can checkout :

- https://pygame-web.github.io/
- https://github.com/pygame-web/pygbag
- https://pypi.org/project/pygbag/

For more information you can checkout

- The `pygame-ce` discord.(pygame-community discord)

Answer (score -1):

If you're not fully committed to pygame, you could investigate the [pyjsdl](https://gatc.ca/projects/pyjsdl/) project which is modelled on pygame. You'd still have to translate your code.

Another alternative is to create stand-alone executable of your existing pygame projects using [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) and distribute those.

[Kivy](https://kivy.org/) can generate HTML5 apps, e.g. [here's a tutorial on creating pong](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html). It's not *really* directed at games.

Or you could consider redeveloping using a web game library in a different language ([probably javascript](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/308/top-15-best-open-source-javascript-game-engines)).

Comment: do you know which one of the above methods is better for collecting user data?

Comment: @jigz it depends on what sort of data you want to gather, the users click-speed, their browser footprint? I think you'd be better off with a framework designed for web.

Comment: I just need to record their input. For instance, consider their are playing a grid-world game with keyboard (i.e., changing the state of their agent). I want to save the game data so I can replay later. Does this make sense?

Comment: If you're already handling events @jigz, then you can extend the existing handler to log the actions for replay etc.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried several options.

1. Trinket.io didn't work well to me since it is cropping the game screen.
2. itch.io requires a downloadable file which I didn't have
3. I tried to use http://www.skulpt.org/, but it didn't even open.
4. So I ended up using replit.com, since this was the only site that didn't crop the game and could host pygame app in browser