# Where can i host my Pygame, or how can i rewrite it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, pygame

So i'm trying to host my pygame as a webgame, i have tried itch.io and did a little research, so there are actually 2 solutions to this, either transforming my pygame into javascript code, or finding a website that hosts my pygame. Is there any automatic way of transfroming my game into java? and if not, is there any website that hosts python games? I'm also considering making a website just to host it but unfortunately idk HTML, i'm learning programming on the side so i don't have that much time on my hands and i'm still a beginner. I'd appreciate some help on this manner<3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a Pygame game executable online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588601/how-can-i-make-a-pygame-game-executable-online)

Comment: You can take a look into this: https://brython.info/

Answer (score -1):

firstly, javascript and java are totally different
secondly, you cant 'automate' code translation

you can use http://pyjs.org/ (pyjs) and try python to js compiler (idk if it works)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can use https://gatc.ca/projects/pyjsdl/. (pyjsl) I think it  work